# Is there any drawback of laragon compared to xampp?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, laragon

I was having trouble while installing xampp in my pc. And then i found laragon easy to install and quite simpler as well as user friendly compared to xampp. But why xampp is so popular among the dev peoples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@mohammad mazharul: Laragon is quite young compare to XAMPP and Laragon is only available on Windows.
More and more developers are adopting Laragon. They love Laragon and spread the news. Just a timing then you'll see Laragon will be more popular.

Comment: Got info. Though ans is not satisfactory. I was expecting some details about performance issues , advantages and disadvantages between them.

Comment: If I remember correctly laragon was developed during the time Laravel was a very popular framework. That is where the 'lara' name came from and I used laragon a lot during that time when I develop projects using laravel.

Answer (score 3):

XAMPP was initially released in September 2002. It became popular because it provided for the first time easy installation for Apache web server, mysql, PHP and Perl. In more than 18 years it has been installed in countless computers. It is also very popular because of numerous tutorials and books.

Laragon on the other hand is far more younger. It has been released 7 years ago only for Windows. Since March 2021 it has also been released  for Linux. With Laragon you are not limited to Apache. NGINX web server is listening on port 8080 (or what ever you want) if you activate it with one click only. Xdebug3 for php was also very easy to integrate. A bunch of other PHP extensions can be activated by one click only.

In my experience there is no drawback but many advantages for Laragon compared to XAMPP.

Answer (score 2):

Laragon is much better than XAMPP, in my experience. Easier to setup, easier to implement features like SSL, easier to upgrade PHP versions, stable, considerably faster.